# About navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition

Tags: geolocation, navigator

i have a question about this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348338/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-doesnt-work-on-android-google-chrome). navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition does not seems to work for me on Android 4.2.2 on many browsers and 4 devices. It ask about my location, I can accept or decline but whatever I pick it does not fire success or errorr function.

My sample code:

```
function GoogleMap(){
    this.initialize = function(){
        if(navigator.geolocation){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess,geolocationError);
        } else {
            geolocationError();
        }
    }
}
function geolocationSuccess(position){
    alert(position);
}
function geolocationError(){
    alert('Geolocation disabled');
}
```

Can You help me with that?

Comment: You can find details in this link [getcurrentposition-sometimes-works-sometimes-doesnt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397585/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-sometimes-works-sometimes-doesnt). I would suggest you to use **timeout** and handle it in error function.

Comment: Thanks, I did a timeout() and it does work for some devices.