# Html geolocation not asking for permission on Localhost app?

Tags: javascript, android, html, spring-mvc, geolocation

I have a `Spring Mvc` web app, placed on a Tomcat server on my localhost.
In one of the pages, I'm using this code, available on [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/)

On Pc it works, but on my phone(Google Chrome), it's not asking for permission, it's denying instantly. Also checked on Chrome, and my app does not appear on blocked app, at location tab.

If I access that fiddle on my phone, it's asking for permission and it's working.

But on my  `192.168.0.xyz:8080/myapp`  ,the permission is denied by default. How can I solve this problem?

Also, I tried `192.168.0.xyz:8080/myapp` on mozzila(android) and default android web browser and it's asking for my permission.
I don't know why chrome(android) is refusing my app for location-, but chrome(pc) works fine..

LE: I tried my app from 2 more android devices, still, the same result!

Comment: try to clear the cache since you might have declined it in the past. also you need to check the settings of the browser, for me it works normally.

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with that, because I tried my app from 2 more android devices, still, the same result!

Comment: I'm not sure then, but you can check this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/a/17441771/5384679

Comment: I'm getting permission denied, not timeout. So..that link is not helping

Answer (score 0):

I partially solved it.
I think it's a bug of Google...
Uninstalled all Google Chrome's updates, and now it's asking for permission

Answer (score 0):

> Note: As of Chrome 50, the Geolocation API will only work on secure contexts such as HTTPS. If your site is hosted on an non-secure origin (such as HTTP) the requests to get the users location will no longer function.

[Source (www.w3schools.com)](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) ([web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20220105201833/https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp))

A more easier solution is to setup a port forwarding between your computer and your phone so you don't need to use HTTPS.
[How to do it](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/local-server/)

You should therefore install a local HTTPS web server or use a service that offers HTTPS hosting like [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) which hosts your web app for free.